# Update MySQL database when a dropdown menu is opened (NB)

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a notification dropdown (like facebook) which shows notifications that are stored in my DB.

I would like to mark the notification as read when the user drops down the notification "menu". Is this possible? and if so can anyone help me do this?

The database stores the information in the field 'notification_read' and this is either set to 0 or 1 (0 for unread).

Thank you and sorry I am a NB

Example of my dropdown menu code

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu notifications arrow">
                    <li class="dd-header">
                        <span>You have 3 new notification(s)</span>
                        <span><a href="#">Mark all Seen</a></span>
                    </li>
                    <div class="scrollthis">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="notification-user active">
                                <span class="time">4 mins</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                <span class="msg">New user Registered. </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into much detail (since this is pretty broad and I don't know the structure of your code), you essentially need two things:

1. A server-side script which updates the database.  This could accept parameters of what to update, or it could just be a global operation to mark all items as read for the current user.  (I'll assume the latter.)
2. Client-side code to invoke the server-side script via AJAX.

For the server-side script, it would be a separate standalone "page" for simplicity.  If we assume there are no parameters and that it can infer the current user from the session, then all this script needs to do is execute whatever your SQL code is to perform the update.  Then it can return (well, "print to the page") something as simple as `true` or `false` to indicate if the update was successful or not.  (If it isn't successful, be sure to log the error somewhere so you can diagnose the problem.)

Let's assume this is called `markAsRead.php`.

Now for the client-side script, that could be something as simple as this (assuming jQuery, because it's easier to free-hand it):

```
$.get('markAsRead.php');
```

Or if the client-side code needs to respond in some way, such as changing the styling from the menu:

```
$.get('markAsRead.php', function (data) {
    // examine data for the response, which from the above
    // description could just be a "true" or "false", and
    // perform client-side logic based on that response
});
```

This client-side code would just be invoked in whatever handler you're using.  For example, if there's some `div` called `#messages` that's being clicked by the user, it might look like this:

```
$('#messages').click(function () {
    $.get('markAsRead.php', function (data) {
        // examine data for the response, which from the above
        // description could just be a "true" or "false", and
        // perform client-side logic based on that response
    });
});
```

Overall, the point is that client-side code responds to the UI event (click), sends a request to a server-side resource which in turn performs the server-side logic, and then reads the response from that resource to perform any additional client-side logic.

Comment: Thank you! I have added some of my code into the question, what would I need to do to this?

Comment: @user4547025: Well, again, this is a very broad question and reaches somewhat outside the scope of what Stack Overflow provides.  *In general*, what you'll need to do is write JavaScript code to respond to the click event.  (There are *many* examples and tutorials online of how to do that.)  In that code you'd perform an AJAX request to the server-side code described in this answer.  (Again, *many* examples of AJAX are available.)  And the server-side code would update the database.  (Same response, lots of examples and tutorials are available.)